# Pandas to_datetime () function performance issues

Tags: python, pandas

Have a df like that:

```
Dat
10/01/2016
11/01/2014
12/02/2013
```

The column 'Dat' has object type so I trying to switch it to datetime using to_datetime () pandas function that way:

```
to_datetime_rand = partial(pd.to_datetime, format='%m/%d/%Y')
df['DAT'] =   df['DAT'].apply(to_datetime_rand)
```

Everything works well but I have performance issues when my df is higher than 2 billion rows. So in that case this method stucks and does not work well.

Does pandas to_datetime () function has an ability to do the convertation by chuncks or maybe iterationally by looping.

Thanks.

Comment: Are the dates unique? If not you could use a dict to store the new datetime values and strings so it doesn't need to convert if it's seen the date before, additionally any reason you can't just do `df['DAT'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DAT'], format='%m/%d/%Y')`?

Comment: Definitely don't use `.apply`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If performance is a concern I would advise to use the following function to convert those columns to `date_time`:

```
def lookup(s):
    """
    This is an extremely fast approach to datetime parsing.
    For large data, the same dates are often repeated. Rather than
    re-parse these, we store all unique dates, parse them, and
    use a lookup to convert all dates.
    """
    dates = {date:pd.to_datetime(date) for date in s.unique()}
    return s.apply(lambda v: dates[v])
```

> ```
> to_datetime: 5799 ms
> dateutil:    5162 ms
> strptime:    1651 ms
> manual:       242 ms
> lookup:        32 ms
> ```

Comment: Hey, this is the second time I see your very smart answer. I was wondering if you did tests around the same optimization concept with another algorithm using categoricals. I was thinking about turning the column to categorical with the labels turned into dates (see http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html#string-and-datetime-accessors). Let me know if you have a chance to test it and compare to your current above benchmark. Thanks!

Comment: I will have a look at this this weekend sometime, check back on Tuesday and I will add an edit. if you have any particular caveats maybe post a question and I will bookmark it and aim to answer appropriately.

Comment: This exact issue has been open for a while, and implementation is pretty simple: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11665 if someone is interested

Comment: I currently are using the apply() method with to_datetime, how would you apply the lookup function in this answer on a similar context?
IE assume you dont know what the name of the columns that must be converted to datetime datatype and you want it to be inferred:
current code: `pandasDF.apply(pd.to_datetime, errors='coerce')`

Answer (score 5):

UPDATE: This enhancement has been incorporated into [pandas 0.23.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html?highlight=to_datetime#pandas.to_datetime)

> **cache** : *boolean,* *default False*
>
> If True, use a cache of unique, converted dates to apply the datetime
>   conversion. May produce significant speed-up when parsing duplicate
>   date strings, especially ones with timezone offsets.

Comment: This reduced the time on a large DF for me from > 30 min to < 3 minutes.

Answer (score 3):

You could split into chunks your huge dataframe into smaller ones, for example this method can do it where you can decide what is the chunk size:

```
def splitDataFrameIntoSmaller(df, chunkSize = 10000): 
    listOfDf = list()
    numberChunks = len(df) // chunkSize + 1
    for i in range(numberChunks):
        listOfDf.append(df[i*chunkSize:(i+1)*chunkSize])
    return listOfDf
```

After you have chunks, you can apply the datetime function on each chunk separately.

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this same issue myself.  Thanks to SerialDev for the excellent answer.  To build on that, I tried using datetime.strptime instead of pd.to_datetime:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

dates = {date : dt.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y') for date in df['DAT'].unique()}
df['DAT'] = df['DAT'].apply(lambda v: dates[v])
```

The strptime method was 6.5x faster than the to_datetime method for me.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired from the previous answers, in the case of having both performance problems and multiple date formats I suggest the following solution.

```
for date in df['DAT'].unique():
    for ft in ['%Y/%m/%d', '%Y']:
        try:
            dates[date] = datetime.strptime(date, ft) if date else None
        except ValueError:
            continue
df['DAT'] = df['DAT'].apply(lambda v: dates[v])
```